# Does AWS S3 cross-region replication use same URL for multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using S3 cross-region replication, if a user downloads http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myobject , will it automatically download from the closest region like cloudfront? So no need to specify the region in the URL like http://mybucket.s3-[region].amazonaws.com/myobject ?

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/03/amazon-s3-introduces-cross-region-replication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bucket names are global, and cross-region replication involves copying it to a *different* bucket.

In other words, example.us-west-1 and example.us-east-1 is not valid, as there can only be one bucket named 'example'.

That's implied in [the announcement post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/)- Mr. Barr is using buckets named jbarr and jbarr-replication.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it had to be a completely different bucket name. I thought it was the same bucket name, just in a different region. I guess you still have to use CloudFront if you want the same URL to go to different regions.

Thanks for that link. That was a much more useful example than the brief announcement I had seen.

Comment: yeah, S3 isn't really a high-performance web server, and shouldn't be thought of that way. CloudFront is cheaper and faster in almost every case. And yeah, it was hard to parse the announcement. I speak fairly fluent AWS.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question "automatically download from the closest region like cloudfront?"

Answer (score 2):

Note: I have an updated version of this answer in the article here: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws/articles/76250275/always-on-access-for-your-data-in-amazon-s3-using-cross-region-replication-and

---

Using S3 cross-Region replication will put your object into two (or more) buckets in two different Regions.

If you want a single access point that will choose the closest available bucket then you want to use [Multi-Region Access Points (MRAP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPoints.html)

MRAP makes use of Global Accelerator and puts bucket requests onto the AWS backbone at the closest edge location, which provides faster, more reliable connection to the actual bucket.  Global Accelerator also chooses the closest available bucket. If a bucket is not available, it will serve the request from the other bucket providing automatic *failover*

You can also configure it in an active/passive configuration, always serving from one bucket until you initiate a failover
[image: MRAP failover]

From the MRAP page on AWS console it even shows you a graphical representation of your replication rules
[image: replication graphic]

Answer (score -1):

s3 is global service, no need specify the region.  The S3 name has to be unique globally.

when you create s3, you need specify the region, however it doesn't mean you need put the region name when you access it.   To speed up the access speed from other region, there are several options like
-- Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration with same bucket name.
-- Or use set up another bucket with different name in different region and enable cross region replication.  Create an origin group with two origins for cloudfront.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question "automatically download from the closest region like cloudfront?"